# Kendo dropdownlist custom filter

Tags: filter, kendo-ui, telerik, dropdown, kendo-dropdown

I want to filter dropdownlist data on multiple columns. Currenly it filter data based on one column.

Is there any custom way to filter data based on multiple columns?

Code :

```
$('<input data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
                        .appendTo(container)
                        .kendoDropDownList({
                         filter: "contains",

                        dataTextField:currentComboEditor.fieldName,
                        headerTemplate: dropdownTemplateHTML.getHeaderHTML(dropdownMetadata.columns),
                        valueTemplate: '<span>#:data.'+currentComboEditor.fieldName+'#</span>',
                        template: dropdownTemplateHTML.getRowTemplate(dropdownMetadata.columns),
                        dataValueField: currentComboEditor.fieldName,
                        dataSource: {
                            data: source
                        } 
                        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built-in  way to filter a `kendoDropDownList` on multiple column.  The only way you could do this would be by creating your own filter:

```
var filterValue = "search me";
var newFilter = {
    logic: "or",
    filters: [
        { field: "FieldA", operator: "contains", value: filterValue },
        { field: "FieldB", operator: "contains", value: filterValue },
        { field: "FieldC", operator: "contains", value: filterValue }
   ]
};
kendoDropDownList.dataSource.filter(newFilter);
```

Depending on your needs, you'll have to hook this code on the right events.

Answer (score 2):

override [Kendo dropdownlist filtering event](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist/events/filtering)

```
kendoDropDownList.bind("filtering", function(e) {
    // ignore space
    var filterValue = e.sender._prev;
    if(filterValue.trim)filterValue = filterValue.trim();

    var newFilter = {
        logic: "or",
        filters: [
            { field: "FieldA", operator: "contains", value: filterValue },
            { field: "FieldB", operator: "contains", value: filterValue },
            { field: "FieldC", operator: "contains", value: filterValue }
       ]
    };
    this.dataSource.filter(newFilter);

    // important: stop default filter
    e.preventDefault();
});
```